# Какие есть библиотеки для реализации загрузки xlsx файла, кроме Apache POI?

Tags: java

такой вопрос, а есть ли еще способы загрузки xlsx файлов, кроме подключения Apache POI? Просто у меня Apache может загружать только xls файлы, а вот с xlsx выдает ошибку.

Comment: [POI 3.8](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/) поддерживает чтение `xlsx` файлов.

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar знаю, но при их считывании выдается ошибка, а разобраться с ее исправлением никак не выходит(

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=xlsx

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтин может быть вы читаете потоком? `xlsx` пока нельзя читать потоком SAX, работает только DOM модель

Comment: Попробуйте [docx4j](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar, я читаю используя это функцию:
"Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(Global_variable.Uri_for_picker.getPath()));
"

Comment: Ну все понятно. Создание книг/шитов в POI пока не поддерживается

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar как правильно реализовать чтение xlsx файла?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге все оказалось хоть и запутано, но не так сложно. Как я понял проблема связана с тем, что Apache POI полностью совместим с android только в версии 3.17, когда другие версии работаю частично.
Вот мое решение:
Сначала в gradle(allproject) добавляем:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext {
        poiVersion = '3.17'
    }
    ...
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

После надо добавить в dependencies из файла build.gradle:

implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion"

Вот на всякий случай мой полный Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true  // this line will solve this problem
        applicationId "com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion"
    ...
    }
```